# deleting a developer profile

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, certificate, xcode4.5

I would like to remove my developer profile from xcode, because I'm not sure if xcode is using the profile I want.

So, with the organizer I delete it, but I'm able to install my app in the device, so, it is not deleted, is it?

how can I remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple places where a provisioning profile would be cached. Organizer is only one place. When building the app it creates a copy in a temporary location. Then the built product also has a copy as embedded.mobileprovision. When the app gets installed on the device the profile is copied into the device's profile store.

So to completely get rid of all instances of the profile:

- delete in organizer
- delete your build folder
- go into preferences - general on the device and remove the profile there as well